# Keydown function does not work in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html

Can any one please tell me why the `keydown` function of JavaScript does not work in Internet Explorer 11?
I do not want to use `$(document).keydown` as it will always fire. 
I want to limit the `keydown` to just a textbox.

Following is the code

```js
$('#country-name').on('keydown', function(e) {

  if (e.which == 40) {
    var totalCountries = $("a.anchor:visible").length;

    window.count = parseInt($("#counter").text());

    if (window.count >= totalCountries) {
      console.log('hi');
      $("#counter").text("0");
      $(".scroll-control")[0].focus();
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }


    $("a.anchor:visible")[window.count].focus();

    window.count = window.count + 1;

    $("#counter").text(window.count);

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(window.count);
  }

});


$('.country').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40) {

    var totalCountries = $("a.anchor:visible").length;

    window.count = parseInt($("#counter").text());

    if (window.count >= totalCountries) {
      console.log('hi');
      $("#counter").text("0");
      $(".scroll-control")[0].focus();
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }


    $("a.anchor:visible")[window.count].focus();

    window.count = window.count + 1;

    $("#counter").text(window.count);



    e.preventDefault();


    console.log(window.count);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give more info about the context (the html part) and the exact problem.

Here is a basic fiddle showing that keydown works in IE 11 for specific inputs :

```js
$('.checkKeydown, #area1').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40) {
    $("#result1").html('detected in ' + e.target.type);
  }
});

$('.checkKeydown, #area1').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 40) {
    $("#result2").html('detected in ' + e.target.type);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="checkKeydown">
  <option>Press Down key...</option>
</select>
<input class="checkKeydown" placeholder="Press down key..." />
<textarea id="area1" placeholder="Press down key..."></textarea>
<input placeholder="Not handled..." />
<br/> on.('keydown') : <span id='result1'></span>
<br/> .keydown : <span id='result2'></span>
```